# HTML href does not link to expected location because of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to link to a html file on my harddrive. For now I have my index.html which schould link to site2.html in the same folder.

```
<a href="site2.html">Site 2</a>
```

The site should link to the second site, which is in the same folder. But it does link nowhere. In my browser the href tag is shown as such:

```
<a href="/site2/">Site 2</a>
```

How can I link to the expected location?

EDIT:

I made a website on Jimdo and now I want it to locally work. Now the problem is that every change I make is not made on the website itself. It looks like there is a JavaScript script preventing changes. It looks like the script links to the actual Jimdo Website, but without redirecting.
This is some code from the JavaScript:

```
window.__WEBSITE_PROPS__ = { * , navigationTree": [{"name:" "site2", *, "slug:" "site2", * }] * }
```

Comment: Have you tried `./site2.html`?

Comment: Yes, it show still the same

Comment: Are you editing the same index.html that you're running in the browser?

Comment: Yes in the browser it has the exact location of the file on the harddrive.

Comment: If you change anything else in that file, do the changes appear in the browser?

Comment: I tired changing the "site2" part to "site2 and fun". If I reload the page now, at first the "site2 and fun" part is shown, then it shows the "site2" part again.
I have no other index.html in this directory.

Comment: @escribe do you have any JavaScript on that page?

Comment: Yes I am editing this site from Jimdo. There is JavaScript on that page.

Comment: I'm wondering if the JavaScript is somehow overriding your changes. I'm not familiar with Jimdo, though. Could you please add a screenshot to your question? That'll help everyone visualize what's going on because this seems weird.

Comment: It looks like, if JavaScript is activated the site is loaded from the harddrive, if JavaScript is deactivated the site is loaded from somewhere else. Possibly Jimdo

Comment: From what should I add screenshots. I can not show complete code, just snippets. I can also show screenshots from the website itself.

Comment: It looks like there is JavaScript that changes the website in the HTML.
` window.__WEBSITE_PROPS__ =  { * , navigationTree": [{"name:" "site2", *, "slug:" "site2", * }] * } `.
The slug-tag is most likely linking to the other website. What exactly is slug?

Comment: @escribe please **edit** and add this information and code to your question. Thanks

Comment: and [about slugs](https://prettylinks.com/2018/03/url-slugs/)

Comment: I looked through the JavaScript code and it looks like, the whole website is built with the JavaScript after the website has initially loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I made the website with Jimdo there is some JavaScript that loads or builds the whole website always from the Jimdo server. I still have no permanent solution but if you have the same problem, just remove the JavaScript and everything should work nicely.

Snippets from the JavaSccript code:

```
window.__WEBSITE_PROPS__ =
        {
            "basePath": "/", "websiteId": "330de313-d32b-4309-9a22-6c591781b107",   
            ...
            "pagePathMap":
            {
                "807f7760-9b36-499d-96e7-22cefd4996eb": "index.html",
                "1dec3d7b-46c1-47c1-97b0-c4f86ffcde13": ".themen.html",
                "59bb866a-3663-4d6e-b7a9-72ff25640f9e": "/ablauf.html",
                "52723e9e-9a6b-467c-ab89-14d61559eb57": "\partner.html",
                "92ff761a-9ab2-4a89-bfe9-01c5ee1ef8ea": "faq.html",
                "6eb0383b-f9fc-440f-94ae-2e3fea38002a": "impressum.html",
                "a4bb260b-da6e-45be-8fce-07d05c57bb7f": "datenschutz.html",
                "b85600c7-51c5-4680-98ec-3f70f471b8a3": "cookie_richtlinie.html",
                "2a8bf66b-8fca-44b4-b0e9-7cca3fb5d6f8": "cookie_einstellungen.html"
            },
        };
```

As you can see the pagePathMap prevents the linking from happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="site2.html">Site 2</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/site2.html">Site 2</a>
```

or

```
<a href="./site2.html">Site 2</a>
```

Kindly update your link like this.
also you can read how to add link on anchor [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: I tried all 3 but I did still not get the expected destination. Still shows in the browser "/site2/"

Comment: Code only answers are very low quality and rarely actually helpful to others. Please add some description as to what your answer actually says or delete your answer. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice i will keep it on mind always.